# What is this 2605 thing when you move your mouse to each tag

Tags: support, tags, popups

Whenever I move my mouse to each tags, I see this 2605 thing in front of the number of followers. What does this 2605 thing mean? 2605 views or 2605 posts has this tags?

[image: I can't think of a good image description.]

Comment: Unicode maaadness, it should be a star.

Comment: A character your browser apparently does not support. What browser are you using?

Comment: in my browser ( Chrome ) ,it shows me Star sign

Comment: I am using Firefox and my OS is Windows XP.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you're seeing is a glyph from the [Unicode Fallback Font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallback_font). It should be the BLACK STAR character (★, Unicode: U+2605). The font list for that element is Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, and sans-serif. It seems odd that none of those fonts are on your machine. So I'm wondering if perhaps you're overriding fonts on your Firefox setup.

[image: Hearts and stars and rainbows clovers and blue moons]

When you click this element in succession it begins a toggle cycle:

1. Marking the tag as Favorite
2. Marking the tag as Ignored
3. Clearing the tag of any user-specific significance

Comment: Your star looks cooler than my star! No fair!

Comment: Bigger, brighter... Safari for Windows, right?

Comment: I don't even like Safari when it's on a Mac (pic from Chrome on Mac).

Comment: weird, the star looks way dorkier on chrome for PC

Comment: I guessed Windows from your SO tags, and Safari from the Mac-like font rendering in your screenshot. Teaches me to stereotype.

Comment: Eh, I find OS's to be interchangeable and have a few of each. However, work pays for Windows development.

Comment: I find myself using the whole network less and less since Helvetica is being (or seeming to be) employed more, having a common corruption issue on Windows renders parts (sometimes most parts of) the sites unreadable (without spending more effort to do so than should be required for reading). http://i.imgur.com/DQTWs.png

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: how do I get that amazing UX on my Windows box?